# How was Dink able to be promoted to commander of his own army?

Tags: enders-game

> Dink Meeker had finally accepted command and succeeded Rose the Nose in Rat Army's command.

But the book later establishes:

> He wondered which army they'd give him. Three commanders were graduating soon, including Petra, but it was beyond hope for them to give him Phoenix Army-**no one ever succeeded to command of the same army he was in when he was promoted**.

Comment: It's possible that Dink was traded to another army prior to being made commander... but I don't recall any mention of that anywhere.

Comment: Once Ender arrived at Battle School the previously established rules became more as guidelines. No reason to believe that Dink couldn't have been given command of his own army if Graff felt that it would help challenge Ender.

Comment: @Xantec While that it is a great explanation which I didn't think of, a possible problem with it would be that Ender's reasoning of "*no one ever succeeded to command of the same army he was in when he was promoted*" happens *after* Dink gets promoted.

Comment: I can't figure out if Dink was promoted to Commander after Ender had already left or before. If it was after, then Ender already set the precedent.

Answer (score 2):

Well, it does say that Ender had been moved to Phoenix army. So, it is a possibility that Dink had been transferred to another army and the received command of Rat. I don't know for sure. Of course there's always the possibility of Orson Scott Card making a mistake which is hard for any author not to.